# Powershell: Loop through sub-directories and move files

Tags: powershell

I'm targeting simple task.
I would like to create folder of constant name "jpg" in all subfolders of supplied root folder "D:Temp\IMG" and move all files in every subfolder with extension ".jpg" to that newly created "jpg" folder.

I thought I'll be able to solve this by myself without deep knowledge of powershell, but it seems I have to ask.

So far, I created this code

```
$Directory = dir D:\Temp\IMG\ | ?{$_.PSISContainer};
foreach ($d in $Directory) {
Write-Host "Working on directory $($d.FullName)..."
Get-ChildItem -Path "$($d.FullName)" -File -Recurse -Filter '*.jpg' |
  ForEach-Object {
      $Dest = "$($d.DirectoryName)\jpg"
      If (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $Dest))
      {New-Item -Path $Dest -ItemType 'Directory' -Force}

      Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Dest
  }
}
```

What I'm getting out of this is infinite loop of folder "jpg" creation in every subfolder.
Where is my code and logic failing here, please?

Comment: the way you have the GCI set up means it will read the new dirs ... and then act on them. [*grin*] either read the whole GCI into a $Var and then iterate thru that, OR add a test to exclude the `jpg` dirs.

Comment: Is your code copied and pasted? Because `$Dest = "$($d.DirectoryName)\jpg"` is wrong, it should be `$Dest = "$($_.DirectoryName)\jpg"` to accomplish what you say is happening.

Comment: You could do `|Where{$_.Directory.Name -ne $_.Extension}` before your `ForEach-Object` loop. That should make it ignore files that are already in the right folder.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thank you for your answer, but your advice doesn't seem to work. Did it work for you?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Lovely, thank you guys!

Comment: @Akhilesh Lovely, thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will accomplish what you are attempting, I'm pretty sure. Your original script doesn't actually recurse, despite specifying that you want it to (`Get-ChildItem` has some finicky syntax around that), so I fixed that. Also fixed my suggestion (I forgot that the Extension property includes the preceding dot, so 'FileName.jpg' has '.jpg' as the extension). I added in some checking, and have it throw warnings if the file already exists at the destination.

```
$Directory = dir D:\Temp\IMG\ -Directory
foreach ($d in $Directory) {
    Write-Host "Working on directory $($d.FullName)..."
    Get-ChildItem -Path "$($d.fullname)\*" -File -Recurse -filter '*.jpg' |
        Where{$_.Directory.Name -ne $_.Extension.TrimStart('.')}|
        ForEach-Object {
            $Dest = join-path $d.FullName $_.Extension.TrimStart('.')
            If (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $Dest))
            {New-Item -Path $Dest -ItemType 'Directory' -Force|Out-Null}

            If(Test-Path ($FullDest = Join-Path $Dest $_.Name)){
                Write-Warning "Filename conflict moving:`n     $($_.FullName)`nTo:`n     $FullDest"
            }Else{
                Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Dest -Verbose
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The following script would do the job.

```
$RootFolder = "F:\RootFolder"

$SubFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Directory

Foreach($SubFolder in $SubFolders)
{ 
    $jpgPath = "$($SubFolder.FullName)\jpg"
    New-Item -Path $jpgPath -ItemType Directory -Force

    $jpgFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SubFolder.FullName -Filter "*.jpg"

    Foreach($jpgFile in $jpgFiles)
    {
        Move-Item -Path $jpgFile.FullName -Destination "$jpgPath\"
    }
}
```